# MUI multiple rows edit and delete functionality using MUI DataGrid with single save button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

We are working on MUI datagrid where we are trying to implement bulk edit and delete functionality using MUI datagrid.

We don't see any reference so far for bulk crud operations. We are ready to opt for pro and premium if this feature allows us to do the build, edit, and delete operations on a single save operation.

Technical flow:

The user selects the one or more checkbox and clicks on the edit button.
User are allowed to edit the field on selected rows and click on the save button.
Once the user clicks on the save button, the datagrid must have updated records.

Answer (score 0):

Use `checkBoxSelection` as mentioned [here](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/row-selection/), then use `onRowSelectionModelChange` prop on data grid

`onRowSelectionModelChange` prop gives all ids that are selected and inside this you can define any of your custom method to set all selected IDS

these selected IDS can be used in your delete method, I am unable to imagine a scenario through which you can do bulk edit, but you can use the ids for the same
ex:

```
  const [ids, setIds] = useState([])
  const deleteMultiple = (ids) => {
    // API Call to delete all resources with mentioned IDS
  }
  ...
   return  (  
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        checkboxSelection
        onRowSelectionModelChange={(ids) => setIds(ids)}
      />
    )
```